# Starting a batch file using vb and streaming output to variable in real time

Tags: batch-file, streaming, real-time

(In my program I'm starting a batch file like this:

```
Dim p1 as new process    
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(appdata & "file.bat")
psi.RedirectStandardError = True
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
psi.CreateNoWindow = True
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
psi.UseShellExecute = False
p1 = Process.Start(psi)
```

This batch file outputs one or more new lines every second or so. My goal is to read these lines in real time. I want to have updated data every 0.5-1 second.

```
p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

The above doesn't work. Every method I've tried so far waits for the batch file to finish, which is exactly the moment I don't need the info anymore. :P

There's gotta be something simple I'm missing, but I can't seem to find it.)

EDIT:
using a new trick:

```
AddHandler p1.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf OutputHandler1
AddHandler p1.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf Errorhandler1
miner1.BeginOutputReadLine()

Private Shared Sub OutputHandler1(ByVal sendingProcess As Object, ByVal outLine As DataReceivedEventArgs)
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data) Then
    MsgBox(outLine.Data)
  End If
End Sub
```

same sub for errorHandler1

This works on other processes (in real time), but not on mine unfortunately :P

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain too much about your program structure but I think you should start the batch program in another thread and then keep reading in your main thread (or the opposite) so neither thread will block.